# Set the highest number of heights of few elements to all the elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, height

I have to **get heights of few elements** (Ex: .content-one > .title) and **set the most highest number** to all the items.

```
<div class="content-one">
    <h3 class="title">Section One</h3>
</div>

<div class="content-two">
    <h3 class="title">Section Two</h3>
</div>
```

This is the code I wrote.

```
maxHeight('.content-one');
maxHeight('.content-two');

function maxHeight(element) {
    const contents = document.querySelectorAll(element);

    contents.forEach(function(content) {
        var title = content.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];

        if (title.clientHeight > 20) {
            title.style.height = 40 + "px";
            console.log("done");
        }
    });
}
```

Here, it checks the heights and try to set the height. But it only set height for elements with height > 20. What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: Why is 40 the "most highest number" here? Why is there even an `if` if that's clearly not what you want?

Comment: @Luca this is the best solution I find. I want to set the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

Get height of first element and write it to some variable (let's say `highest`). Then you have to iterate over elements and check `if(highest < myNextElemHeight) {highest = myNextElemHeight}`. After the loop, you'll get the highest value of element and then in another loop you can set high of all elements to `highest` value.

You have to declare `highest` outside (before) the loop.

Answer (score 0):

@Suresh.W, try with given solution, with first loop you have to fetch highest  height then you can assign it to your control

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   maxHeight('.content-one');
maxHeight('.content-two');

function maxHeight(element) {
    const contents = document.querySelectorAll(element);
    var allHeight = [];
    var setheight= 40;
    contents.forEach(function(content) {
        var title = content.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];
        allHeight.push(title.clientHeight);
        if(Math.max(allHeight) > 20)
          setheight = 40;
        else
          setheight = Math.max(allHeight);
        
    });
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
    var index = 0, length = elems.length;
    for ( ; index < length; index++) {
        elems[index].style.height =setheight + "px";  
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-one">
    <h4 class="title">Section One</h4>
</div>

<div class="content-two">
    <h3 class="title">Section Two</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfectly working. But the issue is this sets the height for all elements with .title class. It should only set the .title elements in .content-one or .content-two

Comment: so if the hight is 18px then i need to set it with .content-one, .title if i call  maxHeight('.content-one')  and in case of calling maxHeight('.content-two') .content-one, .title  the same hight will be there right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the interest. I couldn't above examples as it is. I have managed to refer & write my own solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    maxHeight('.content-one');
    maxHeight('.content-two');

    function maxHeight(element) {
        const contents = document.querySelectorAll(element);
        var titleHeight = 0;

        contents.forEach(function(content) {
            var title = content.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];

            if (title.clientHeight > titleHeight) {
                titleHeight = title.clientHeight;
            }
        });

        contents.forEach(function(content) {
            var title = content.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];
            title.style.minHeight = titleHeight + "px";
        });
    }
});
```